# Converting epoch to datetime in PySpark data frame using udf

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with this schema:

```
root
 |-- epoch: double (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: double (nullable = true)
```

Where epoch is in seconds and should be converted to date time. In order to do so, I define a user defined function (udf) as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf    
import time
def epoch_to_datetime(x):
    return time.localtime(x)
    # return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(x))
    # return x * 0 + 1

epoch_to_datetime_udf = udf(epoch_to_datetime, DoubleType())
df.withColumn("datetime", epoch_to_datetime(df2.epoch)).show()
```

I get this error:

```
---> 21     return time.localtime(x)
    22     # return x * 0 + 1
    23 
    TypeError: a float is required
```

If I simply return `x + 1` in the function, it works. Trying `float(x)` or `float(str(x))` or `numpy.float(x)` in `time.localtime(x)` does not help and I still get an error. Outside of `udf`, `time.localtime(1.514687216E9)` or other numbers works fine. Using `datetime` package to convert `epoch` to datetim results in similar errors.

It seems that `time` and `datetime` packages do not like to fed with `DoubleType` from PySpark. Any ideas how I can solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Your `udf` didn't work because `time.localtime()` does not return a `float` or `double` (as you defined your udf), but rather a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**You don't need a `udf` function for that**

All you need is to *cast the double epoch column to `timestampType()`* and then use `data_format` function as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
df.withColumn('epoch', f.date_format(df.epoch.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

this will give you a string date

```
root
 |-- epoch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: double (nullable = true)
```

And you can use `to_date` function as following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
df.withColumn('epoch', f.to_date(df.epoch.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType())))
```

which would give you `date` as `datatype` to `epoch` column

```
root
 |-- epoch: date (nullable = true)
 |-- var1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- var2: double (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 5):

[Ramesh Maharjan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49972862/4006204) does not support getting milliseconds or microseconds in Timestamp. The updated answer to add support for milliseconds is as follows:

Implementing the approach suggested in [Dao Thi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49972862/4006204)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC', ),('23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC',)], ['TIME'])
df.show(2,False)
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|TIME                        |
+----------------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|
+----------------------------+
root
|-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
```

Converting **string time-format** (including milliseconds ) to **unix_timestamp(double)**. Extracting milliseconds from string using substring method (start_position = -7, length_of_substring=3) and Adding milliseconds seperately to unix_timestamp. (Cast  to substring to float for adding)

```
df1 = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp",F.unix_timestamp(df.TIME,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z') + F.substring(df.TIME,-7,3).cast('float')/1000)
```

Converting **unix_timestamp(double)** to **timestamp datatype** in Spark.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("TimestampType",F.to_timestamp(df1["unix_timestamp"]))
df2.show(n=2,truncate=False)
```

This will give you following output

```
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|TIME                        |unix_timestamp  |TimestampType          |
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|1.532233278792E9|2018-07-22 04:21:18.792|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|1.532319685888E9|2018-07-23 04:21:25.888|
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Checking the Schema:

```
df2.printSchema()


root
 |-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unix_timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TimestampType: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I tried on my cluster, and maybe it is an old pyspark version.
I got the following error message: http://pasteb.com/f85h 
Supporting double format as input to F.to_timestamp is a new feature?

thanks

Comment: Why -7 to 3? It seems like 11, 3 should work

Comment: Alternatively, if the epoch is in milliseconds, divide by 1000, then convert to timestamp.... ```df.withColumn('timestamp2', f.to_timestamp(df.timestamp/1000)).show()```

Answer (score 5):

For me i need to convert the long timestamp back to date format.

I used @Glicth comment which worked for me. - might help other.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit
from datetime import datetime

df001 = spark.createDataFrame([(1639518261056, ),(1639518260824,)], ['timestamp_long'])
df002 = df001.withColumn("timestamp",f.to_timestamp(df001['timestamp_long']/1000))
df001.printSchema()
display(df002)
```

schema

```
root
 |-- timestamp_long: long (nullable = true)
```

Using Databricks: output of `display(df002)`
[image]