# Converting Epoch Time to Timestamp in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, epoch

I have a df with a column having epoch time. The variable type of the epoch timecolumn is string. I want it to convert into Timestamp. I am using the following command

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp
df = df.withColumn('start_time',from_unixtime(df.recognition_start_time,'UTC'))
df.select('recognition_start_time').show(10,False)
```

But the command is giving me null as a result. What is the mistake I am making?

```
Epoch Time : 1583471040000
Output expected :2020-03-06 05:04:00
```

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971903/converting-epoch-to-datetime-in-pyspark-data-frame-using-udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **`from_unixtime`** we need to specify the expected output format(`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`) and by using **`from_utc_timestamp`** we can convert the output from utc to given timezone.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("""select from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime("1583471040000"/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),"America/Chicago")""").show(false)
+---------------------+
|_c0                  |
+---------------------+
|2020-03-05 05:04:00.0|
+---------------------+
```